# How to import/export Api from wso2 Api Manager?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am unable to import/export Api from wso2 Api manager.. so can have alternative ways and any tool ?

I have downloaded one API (as api.zip file), which I created in WSO2 API Manager from the Administation console. Is there a way to import this API in different WSO2 instance?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the archive created to import APIs to an API Manager instance. You can have a look on our API import/export tool [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM191/Migrating+the+APIs+to+a+Different+Environment)

Comment: What is the right value to be specified for Version?

Comment: curl -H "Authorization:Basic AbCdEfG" -X GET 
"https://10.100.7.40:9443/api-import-export-<version>/export-api?name=WeatherAPI&version=1.0.0&provider=admin"
-k > myExportedAPI.zip

Comment: It's the tool version which you downloaded, it can be either v0.9.1 or v0.9.0.

Comment: it is  version  v0.9.0

Comment: Have you successfully completed?

Comment: No..  i had imported only swagger.yaml page that means GET POST or PUT ready-made URL available newly created in wso2 app but  i am using wso2 only for locally in the system.  My requirement how to use the same app for globally. How import/export to globally in this application. ?